# Connect helm to multiple tiller in different k8s clusters

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to manage different clusters of k8s,
one called `production` for prod deployments,
and another one called `staging` other deployments and configurations.

How can I connect `helm` to the tiller in those 2 different clusters?
Assume that I already have `tiller` installed and I have a configured ci pipeline.

Answer (score 5):

Helm will connect to the same cluster that `kubectl` is pointing to.

By setting multiple `kubectl` contexts and changing them with `kubectl config use-context [environment]`  you can achieve what you want.

Of course you will need to set appropriate HELM_ environment values in your shell for each cluster including TLS certificates if you have them enabled.

Also it’s worth taking steps so that you don’t accidentally deploy to the wrong cluster by mistake.

Comment: After changing contexts with `kubectl config use-context` do we have to re-do `helm init` ?